# ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, mysql

I have one table called incident_log and its structure is this

```sql
CREATE TABLE `incident_log` (
`il_id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,    
`il_i_id` int default NULL,
`il_time_occured` datetime NOT NULL,
`il_status` varChar(255) NOT NULL default 'OPEN',       
`il_prevstate` varChar(255),        
`il_trigger` varchar(255),          
`il_current_state` int NOT NULL default 0, 
`il_prev_state` int NOT NULL default 0, 
`il_current_trigger` int NOT NULL default 0,                    
`il_prev_trigger` int NOT NULL default 0,
`il_pol_as_status` mediumblob,  
`il_obj_id` int,        
`il_occuredCount` int default 0,
`il_reportedOccuredCount` int default 0, 
`il_reportedCount` int default 0,   
`il_cascadeReportedTime` bigint default 0, 
`il_obj1` text,     
`il_obj2` text,     
`il_obj3` text,     
`il_itype` enum('CRITICAL','EVENT') NOT NULL default 'CRITICAL',
`il_usrNotifyStatus` enum('NEW','NOTIFIED','NOT_NOTIFIED') NOT NULL default 'NEW', 
`il_rootcause_il_id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`il_rootcause_info` text DEFAULT NULL,
`il_rootcause_i_objclass` enum('DATASET','COMPONENT','SERVICE','SERVER','BCS') default NULL, 
`il_rootcause_i_obj_id` int(11) default 0,
`il_acset_id` int default NULL, 
`il_intRes1` int, 
`il_intRes2` int, 
`il_intRes3` int, 
`il_intRes4` int, 
`il_varcharRes1` varchar(64), 
`il_varcharRes2` varchar(255) );
```

but when inserting following data it gives me an error

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

```sql
INSERT INTO incident_log  (il_i_id, il_time_occured, il_cascadeReportedTime,
                           il_occuredCount,il_obj_id, il_obj1, il_obj2, il_obj3,
                           il_status, il_rootcause_il_id, il_rootcause_info, 
                           il_rootcause_i_objclass, il_rootcause_i_obj_id, 
                           il_acset_id)  
                  VALUES  (1,'',0,0,12,'','','','OPEN',0,NULL,NULL,0,NULL);
```

Please help me to solve this problem..

Comment: @Anjali Problem in your java code. Kindly post your java code for proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

I have found few corrections in your create table syntax

1. Auto increment column should be defined in primary key
2. You `il_time_occured` in datetime. While inserting `''`(Empty value) through error Incorrect field.

Nothing wrong in your insert statement

This query works fine.

```
INSERT INTO incident_log (il_i_id, il_time_occured, il_cascadeReportedTime, il_occuredCount,il_obj_id, il_obj1, il_obj2, il_obj3, il_status, il_rootcause_il_id, il_rootcause_info, il_rootcause_i_objclass, il_rootcause_i_obj_id, il_acset_id) VALUES (1,'2012-12-27 16:03:32',0,0,12,'','','','OPEN',0,NULL,NULL,0,NULL)
```

Refer the Screen short:
[image]

[See sqlfiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73380)

Comment: 1. that column is defined as primary key only.

Comment: 2. but when i am giving proper value to il_time_occured column then also it gives same error msg.

Comment: INSERT INTO incident_log  (il_i_id, il_time_occured, il_cascadeReportedTime,
                           il_occuredCount,il_obj_id, il_obj1, il_obj2, il_obj3,
                           il_status, il_rootcause_il_id, il_rootcause_info, 
                           il_rootcause_i_objclass, il_rootcause_i_obj_id, 
                           il_acset_id)  
                  VALUES  (1,'2012-12-27 16:03:32',0,0,12,'','','','OPEN',0,NULL,NULL,0,NULL);

Comment: @Anjali See My Edit. Visit SQL Fiddle for Check your Query

Comment: thanks  Dhinakaran Pragasam...but still same problem while running on MySQL prompt and through java